# Best sellers and Flat Catalog?

Tags: flat-catalog, best-seller

I have installed Magento and used a custom theme. I want to use a Best sellers widget on my homepage, but it doesn't work with Flat Catalog I have enabled on categories and products. As I understand the "standard" best sellers widgets don't work with FC enabled.

I must use Flat Catalog because the website has many categories and more than 1000 products.

I haven't found a way to make it work, some old articles from the web and no modules at all. I can't believe that there is no way to offer best sellers and/or most viewed products in larger shops that use FC, so, can someone please point me to the right direction here?

Comment: Which type of products are you define as bestsellers & whicg widget  are u using

Comment: I'm not defining any products, it's supposed to be automatic. I'm using Porto theme and it's best seller widget.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it works with the Best Seller Products Extension, just tested it on a local machine with Flat Catalog enabled and on Manual setting, didn't work with auto-bestsellers. Will test a bit more.

Comment: Keep in mind that the best seller feature as implemented by a lot (copied flawed code) is the number one reason for degrading performance over time. Run the main query through EXPLAIN to see why. If it shows full table scans and temporary tables for sorting, think how that's gonna work with 100k orders.